How to sum by date for a list of items
I use MongoDB version 7. I store the payments data with order and buyer information. I have a few payments in a collection with order and buyer information, which I group by order id to the next JSON result:
{
    "incomeCash": [
        {
            "_id": "64d5fe21fb5b6271ce7934a1",
            "buyer": {
                "title": "buyer1",
                "key": "64234a2711d053037a0362d1"
            },
            "key": "64d5fe21fb5b6271ce7934a1", //order 1 key
            "title": "ORDER 1",
            "payments": [
                {
                    "date": "2023-07-15T00:00:00.000Z",
                    "amount": "1.01"
                }
            ],
            "total": "1.01",
            "direction": "in"
        },
        {
            "_id": "6451db5cd001097cb1f27651",
            "buyer": {
                "title": "buyer1",
                "key": "64234a2711d053037a0362d1"
            },
            "key": "6451db5cd001097cb1f27651", //order 2 key
            "title": "ORDER 2",
            "payments": [
                {
                    "date": "2023-05-08T00:00:00.000Z",
                    "amount": "1.01"
                },
                {
                    "date": "2023-05-18T00:00:00.000Z",
                    "amount": "2.02"
                },
                {
                    "date": "2023-07-15T00:00:00.000Z",
                    "amount": "3.03"
                }
            ],
            "total": "6.06",
            "direction": "in"
        }
    ]
}

So my question is how to group by buyer.key all orders with summarized payments by date, I what to get next JSON style:
[
    {
        "_id": "64234a2711d053037a0362d1",
        "key": "64234a2711d053037a0362d1", //buyer key
        "title": "buyer 1",
        "subLevels": [
            {
                "key": "64d5fe21fb5b6271ce7934a1", //order 1 key
                "title": "ORDER 1",
                "payments": [
                    {
                        "date": "2023-07-15T00:00:00.000Z",
                        "amount": "1.01"
                    }
                ],
                "total": "1.01",
                "direction": "in"
            },
            {
                "key": "6451db5cd001097cb1f27651", //order 2 key
                "title": "ORDER 2",
                "payments": [
                    {
                        "date": "2023-05-08T00:00:00.000Z",
                        "amount": "1.01"
                    },
                    {
                        "date": "2023-05-18T00:00:00.000Z",
                        "amount": "2.02"
                    },
                    {
                        "date": "2023-07-15T00:00:00.000Z",
                        "amount": "3.03"
                    }
                ],
                "total": "6.06",
                "direction": "in"
            }
        ],
        "total": 7.07,
        "payments": [
            {
                "date": "2023-05-08T00:00:00.000Z",
                "amount": "1.01"
            },
            {
                "date": "2023-05-18T00:00:00.000Z",
                "amount": "2.02"
            },
            {
                "date": "2023-07-15T00:00:00.000Z", //group by date
                "amount": "4.04" //sum by date
            }
        ]
    }
]

P.S. All amounts and totals are in decimal type, at the moment I try to use $group with $accumulator and function, but not all amounts are correctly summed, like:
{
  "date": "2023-05-08T00:00:00.000Z",
  "amount": "1.01"
},
{
  "date": "2023-05-18T00:00:00.000Z",
  "amount": "2.02"
},
{
  "date": "2023-07-15T00:00:00.000Z",
  "amount": "NumberDecimal(\"1.01\")NumberDecimal(\"3.03\")"
}

Maybe there is another variant of sum payments by date without function and group with accumulator?

Your expected result is inconsistent. The document In subLevels, some has the payments field and some has items field.

Sorry for this typo, but it's not important, I fix it, thank you

Think that it is a complex query that needs to unwind and group the document multiple times.

$unwind - Deconstruct the payments array into multiple documents.

$group - Group by buyer.key and payments.date to perform sum. And keep the original document in the root field.

unwind - Deconstruct the root array into multiple documents.

$group - Group by root._id so that the output document should be similar as the original document.

$group - Group by buyer.key.

$set - Sort the element in the subLevels and payments array by the date field. The special case is that requires additional steps to remove the duplicate element from the payments array before sorting.


db.incomeCash.aggregate([
  {
    $unwind: "$payments"
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        buyerKey: "$buyer.key",
        date: {
          $toDate: "$payments.date"
        }
      },
      amount: {
        $sum: {
          $toDecimal: "$payments.amount"
        }
      },
      root: {
        $push: "$$ROOT"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: "$root"
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$root._id",
      buyer: {
        $first: "$root.buyer"
      },
      key: {
        $first: "$root.key"
      },
      title: {
        $first: "$root.title"
      },
      payments: {
        $push: "$root.payments"
      },
      sumPayments: {
        $addToSet: {
          date: "$_id.date",
          amount: "$amount"
        }
      },
      total: {
        $first: "$root.total"
      },
      direction: {
        $first: "$root.direction"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$buyer.key",
      title: {
        $first: "$buyer.title"
      },
      subLevels: {
        $addToSet: {
          key: "$key",
          title: "$title",
          payments: "$payments",
          total: "$total",
          direction: "$direction"
        }
      },
      total: {
        $sum: {
          $toDecimal: "$total"
        }
      },
      payments: {
        $push: "$sumPayments"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $set: {
      subLevels: {
        $sortArray: {
          input: "$subLevels",
          sortBy: {
            "payment.date": 1
          }
        }
      },
      payments: {
        $sortArray: {
          input: {
            $reduce: {
              input: "$payments",
              initialValue: [],
              in: {
                $let: {
                  vars: {
                    elem: {
                      $concatArrays: [
                        "$$this",
                        "$$value"
                      ]
                    }
                  },
                  in: {
                    $setUnion: "$$elem"
                  }
                }
              }
            }
          },
          sortBy: {
            date: 1
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])

Demo @ Mongo Playground

Thank you, I will see it now.  One more question, may be you can give me advice. If I had a few sections, like cashBalanceStart, incomeCash, outcomeCash, netCashFlow, cashBalanceEnd I try to use $facet for do logic of each section of report, but got an error about bson document memory error, is only one way to decompose to different aggregations?

Haven't heard of BSON Document memory error. Probably you mean BSON document size error for exceeding 16 MB? If yes, that means the $facet stage results in the document is too large. Probably what you want is working with different (aggregation) query. Then perform the computation/data transform in your backend.

Yep, BSON document size error, $setUnion is that I need, thank you for playground
